# Using JS to force browser to redraw (not refresh) in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, phantomjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to take screencaps of a site I am manipulating with Javascript. I am using PhantomJS for the actual capture, but I am trying out my Javascript in Chrome before I am sending it through Phantom. The way Phantom works is that it navigates to the site, let's you manipulate the site, and then, draws the site with the new variables I have set with Javascript. I am trying to mimic this behavior in Chrome because it is easier to get feedback on the variables I am changing in the Chrome console, but whenever I refresh in Chrome, it resets all of the variables to their initial state without letting me see how the site changes.

I there a way to do something like this in Chrome?

Comment: What sort of variables are you changing?

Comment: The site is a traffic site that uses a Google map to overlay traffic incidents. To tell the map where to put the incidents, it uses an array of locations. I am filtering the array to only display incidents of a certain type or within a given radius.

Comment: I can see the changes in PhantomJS, but the workflow is just kind of clunky.

Comment: Why do your refresh the page in Chrome?

Comment: You could try updating your array of locations in the console, and then running `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` to force the google map to refresh